# generic interface method and implementation classes

Tags: java, generics

I have this interface method in the `Animal` `interface`:

```
<T extends Animal> boolean isEqual(T pAnimal);
```

now I am in trouble with the implementation.
I have two classes `Dog` and `Cat`. Both classes `extends` from `Animal`.
I want to overwrite the method but with the concrete implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean isEqual(Dog pDog) {
  // do some stuff.
  return true;
}
```

this leads to the compile error

```
must override or implement a supertype method
```

How I have to define the interface so that it is not necessary to make a `typecast` in my concrete implementation class?

Thanks in advance

Stefan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would work if you move the type parameter to the interface level :

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends Animal> {
    boolean isEqual(T pAnimal);
}
```

Then

```
public class Dog implements MyInterface<Dog> {
    @Override
    boolean isEquals (Dog dog) {}
}
```